# Can we prove ZFC is consistent?

Tags: first-order-logic

Or can we prove the independence of the CH?

Let's place ourselves in first order logic.

If CH was proved unprovable and ZFC was inconsistent, let P be a paradox in ZFC.

1)We have: P is true
2)And P => CH (since P is false)
3)Therefore CH is true: contradiction..

What's the problem here?

Comment: As far as I recall, the proof of independence of CH from ZFC is predicated on ZFC being consistent.

Comment: In fact, I just looked it up and this is correct. Basically you prove that if ZFC is consistent, then so is ZFC+CH, and so is ZFC+$\neg$CH.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Oh wow yeah it seems so. Now it's clear, thanks !

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip And.. Did we prove that the consistency of ZFC is unprovable in ZFC itself? Or is it still a mystery

Comment: Yes, the consistency of ZFC is unprovable in ZFC (unless of course ZFC is inconsistent). This is exactly Godel's n-th Incompleteness Theorem for a certain value of n.

Comment: As nobody has proved ZFC inconsistent, it remains a 'mystery'. (If it's inconsistent, then *nothing* is independent of it.) If ZFC is consistent then it can't prove its own consistency, by Godel's 2nd Incompleteness theorem.

Comment: The OP is asking why the independence of CH doesn't imply that ZFC is consistent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can certainly prove that ZFC is consistent, but only if you assume some equivalent or stronger theory is consistent.  For example, Morse-Kelly set theory proves that ZFC is consistent, but now you're simply transferring the assumption of consistency from ZFC to MK.  This is a consequence of Godel's incompleteness theorems.  There's no free lunch when it comes to consistency (of sufficiently complex theories).

Now when it comes CH, you are missing a few important details.  CH was *not* proven unprovable, but rather it was proven *independent* of ZFC.  What this means is that it was shown that you can add either CH or $\neg$CH as an additional axiom to ZFC, and assuming that ZFC is consistent, the extended theories ZFC + CH and ZFC + $\neg$CH are also consistent.  So CH's independence already relies on the consistency of ZFC, so you cannot use that fact to prove ZFC is consistent.

So when you say

> If CH was proved unprovable and ZFC was inconsistent

you're basically already at a contradiction since now you're stating that ZFC is both consistent and inconsistent.