# Arithmetic statements believed to be unprovable under any "reasonable" axioms?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Can we name statements about the natural numbers that are (1) unprovable using axioms like $\textrm{ZFC}$, and which we moreover expect to be (2) unprovable under any trusted set of axioms in the future?  That is, can we name a specific question in arithmetic that we expect will never be answered?

Background:
[Some statements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974557/what-are-some-natural-arithmetical-statements-independent-of-zfc) about $\mathbb{N}$ are unprovable by $\textrm{ZFC}$ (if $\textrm{ZFC}$  is consistent).  More generally, by [Godel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Second_incompleteness_theorem), given any consistent formal system containing arithmetic, we can name an arithmetic statement unprovable within that system.  However, even when an arithmetic statement is unprovable within a given system, sometimes we still come to believe it's true, by proving it within some stronger set of trusted axioms. For instance, by the [Paris-Harrington theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris%E2%80%93Harrington_theorem), a certain combinatorial statement is unprovable within Peano arithmetic but proven under $\textrm{ZFC}$.  Or note the consistency of $\textrm{ZFC}$ itself can be formulated as an [arithmetic statement](https://mathoverflow.net/a/32914), and while it's unprovable under $\textrm{ZFC}$ (if $\textrm{con(ZFC)}$), it can be proven under some [alternative axioms](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1649135/900829) deemed reasonable.

Again, no matter what consistent "reasonable axioms" we come to trust in the future, we will be able to name arithmetic statements unprovable within those axioms. Relatedly, we can name a class of binary questions (e.g. the halting problem) that is undecidable by any future Turing machine.  But neither of these directly address the question: I'm wondering whether we can name a *specific* statement that we expect to be unprovable under *any* axioms that we come to agree upon.  (Of course, the statement itself could be added as an axiom, but we would still be skeptical unless there were some reason to believe it.) There's fuzziness when asking about "reasonable axioms we may come to trust in the future," but that's exactly what I'm trying to probe here. I would appreciate if anyone could clarify my thinking or point to relevant discussions.

Related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3309975/are-there-explicit-examples-of-absolutely-unprovable-mathematical-statements?rq=1) and related keyword "absolutely undecidable."

Comment: IMO it is hard to give a precise meaning to "any axioms that we come to agree upon" and "reasonable axioms we may come to trust in the future".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, that part is vague, but still I wouldn't be surprised if there were some clever suggestion for an unprovable statement which somewhat convincingly met my criteria, even without formalizing the criteria.

Comment: As per answer to the linked posts, the undecidable statements imply the axiom of large cardinals; the issue is exactly the this axiom is not "agreed upon".